# How to construct a DFA for truncate the rightmost symbol from a given string?

Tags: automata

If I have a truncate operation defined which removes the rightmost symbol from a string ,for instance I have  a string say aababb so it removes the rightmost symbol b and the output is aabab.

so how to approach this question

Comment: A DFA implements a decision procedure. You can not solve your problem with a DFA.

Comment: As @user3491648 says, a DFA recognises a set of languages, it can not "change" a string, so what exactly are you trying to do and what is your question?

Comment: Maybe she's trying to make a Mealy machine.

Comment: Let us define an operation truncate, which removes the rightmost symbol from any string. for example, truncate(aaaba) is aaab. The operation can
be extended to languages by
truncate(L): {truncate (w) : w€ L}.

Comment: I am not trying to make a mealey machine ,you can check out this question in peter linz book for chapter 2 ,first exercise.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Start with a DFA for the original language $L$, and modify it to get a DFA for the truncated language. The only part of it that you need to change is the set of acceptor (final) states.

> A state should be an acceptor state in the new automaton if there is a transition from it to a state that was an acceptor state in the old one.

Comment: I agree with you but if there is a self loop on final state of original language itself then we should keep this state as it is. i.e we should not convert it from final to non -final state. for example $ab^*$ . If you make the initial state as only  final state (as it is one step away from  final state in original language) then it can not accept $ab$ or $abb$ etc.  right?

Comment: @ViX28: If $q$ is an acceptor state in the original DFA, and there is some transition from $q$ to $q$, then $q$ will automatically remain an acceptor state in the new DFA if you follow the spoiler-protected rule.